# Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path when want to retrieve certain data in the list

Tags: android, database, retrofit

```
    String itemcode;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    itemcode =intent.getStringExtra("itemcode");

        restService.getService().getItemCode(itemcode, new Callback<SPSOnHand>() {
            @Override
            public void success(SPSOnHand student, Response response) {

                item_description.setText(String.valueOf(student.ITEM_DESCRIPTION));
                balance.setText(student.ONHAND_QTY);

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AirJet.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

here my Service

```
@GET("/api/SPSOnHand/itemcode/{item_code}")
    public void getItemCode(@Path("item_code") String itemcode, Callback<SPSOnHand> callback);
```

here my

```
public class SPSOnHand {

    public int ID;
    public String ITEM_CODE;
    public String ITEM_DESCRIPTION;
    public String ONHAND_QTY;
    public String TYPE;
    public String DATE;
    public String OPR_ID;

}
```

Comment: You response is a list, so it should be List< SPSOnHand > in Callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you received an Array or Object from Api response but when you parse it with the wrong type like receive an Array but you parse it using Object or receive Object and parse it with an Array.

In your case, `SPSOnHand` model class should be an Array.

Your service should be

```
@GET("/api/SPSOnHand/itemcode/{item_code}")
    public void getItemCode(@Path("item_code") String itemcode, Callback<ArrayList<SPSOnHand>> callback);
```

based on this you have to update your request and response.

Comment: how i want to call the value inside the array sir in here
            public void success(SPSOnHand student, Response response) {

               here>>>>> item_description.setText(String.valueOf(student.ITEM_DESCRIPTION));
               here>>>>> balance.setText(student.ONHAND_QTY);

            }

Comment: can you please share your response so it will get more idea.

Comment: sir, if u dont mind to check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896926/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-list-in-retrofit

Comment: @NurulNabilaMahadi I have given an answer to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your POJO class expected object but the response was in the list. I recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker) library to track your HTTP connections in debug mode, so you can see what kind of response you receiving easily.