# How to retrieve a value from list in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

here my module

```
public class SPSOnHand { 
    @SerializedName("ITEM_CODE")
    @Expose
    private String ITEM_CODE;
    @SerializedName("ITEM_DESCRIPTION")
    @Expose
    private String ITEM_DESCRIPTION;

    public String getITEM_CODE() {
        return ITEM_CODE;
    }

    public void setITEM_CODE(String item_code) {
        ITEM_CODE = item_code;
    }

    public String getITEM_DESCRIPTION() {
        return ITEM_DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public void setITEM_DESCRIPTION(String item_description) {
        ITEM_DESCRIPTION = item_description;
    }
```

here my rest service class

```
public class RestService {

    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:58364/";
    private retrofit.RestAdapter restAdapter;
    //private InstituteService apiService;
    private SPInventoryService apiService;

    public RestService()
    {
        restAdapter = new retrofit.RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(URL)
                .setLogLevel(retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(SPInventoryService.class);
    }

    public SPInventoryService getService()
    {
        return apiService;
    }
```

here my service

```
@GET("/api/SPSOnHand/itemcode/{item_code}")
public void getItemCode(@Path("item_code") String itemcode, 
Callback<ArrayList<SPSOnHand>>callback);
```

here my main activity class

```
        String itemcode;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        itemcode =intent.getStringExtra("itemcode");

            restService.getService().getItemCode(itemcode, new Callback<ArrayList<SPSOnHand>>() {

                @Override
                public void success(ArrayList<SPSOnHand> spsOnHands, Response response) {
                    item_description.setText(String.valueOf(spsOnHands.get(0)));

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(AirJet.this, error.getMessage().toString(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

[image]

I want that item_description to contain a word like this

```
"ID": 167,
"ITEM_CODE": "3020240002",
"ITEM_DESCRIPTION": "CONTROLLER LME22.331c2 (CONTROL BOX)"
```

thanks in advance, I'm still a newbie in retrofit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you receive `ArrayList`. And if you want to get the item from `List` then you have to pass `index` and get value `List`, like below. It will give you `ITEM_DESCRIPTION` for the 0th index of your `List`.

```
restService.getService().getItemCode(itemcode, new Callback<ArrayList<SPSOnHand>>() {

                @Override
                public void success(ArrayList<SPSOnHand> spsOnHands, Response response) {
                    item_description.setText(String.valueOf(spsOnHands.get(0).ITEM_DESCRIPTION));

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(AirJet.this, error.getMessage().toString(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of `String.valueOf(spsOnHands.get(0))` whole item of list converted to String so that's why you are getting wrong format of text.

Use below code for set text in textview:

```
 int id = 0+1;
 String itemCode = arrayList.get(0).getITEM_CODE();
 String itemDescription = arrayList.get(0).getITEM_CODE();
 item_description.setText("\"ID\":"+ id+" \n\"ITEM_CODE\":" + itemCode+" \n\"ITEM_DESCRIPTION\":"+itemDescription);
```

You can change format of text in textview according to your requirement.